# Vuforia VideoPlayback Fullscreen

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, fullscreen, vuforia, audiovideoplayback

Am new to vuforia and unity. In vuforia's Video playback sample the video plays on the marker and if I double tap and choose Fullscreen from the options it plays in Full screen. I created a UI button and want the video to be played in fullscreen when that UI button is pressed. Please help me out.

Answer (score 2):

Get a reference to the VideoPlaybackBehaviour attached to the video. Then on button press you want to call the VideoPlayer.Play method:

```
//GLOBAL - ASSIGN IN INSPECTOR
public VideoPlaybackBehavior video;

void OnClick() //your button click
{
    video.VideoPlayer.Play(true, 0); //true makes it fullscreen
}
```